# Всем привет, у меня проблемы с валидацией в laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

У нас есть todo лист, в котором у каждого пользователя свои задачи, при валидации добавления, необходимо, чтобы задача была уникальной, сама проблема в том, что оно проверяет все строки в бд, а необходимо только привязанные к нынешнему пользователю. Спасибо за помощь!

Контроллер:

```
public function create(Tasks $obTasks, Request $obRequest)
{
    if ($obRequest->method() === 'POST') {
        $obValidator = Validator::make(
            $obRequest->all(), [
                'title' => ["required", "unique:tasks", "max:255"],

            ], $obTasks->messages, $obTasks->attributes);
        if ($obValidator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(["validationMessage" => $obValidator->errors()->first()]);
        }
        $obTasks->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $obTasks->title = $obRequest->title;
        $obTasks->save();
        return response()->json(['redirect' => route('home')]);
    }
}
```

Таблица tasks состоит из полей: id, timestamps поля, title, user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в unique можно добавлять несколько аргументов, через запятую:
`table, column, ignore, column id, format wheres`.
Вам же можно просто добавить:

```
unique:tasks,title,NULL,id,user_id,Auth::user()->id
```

интерпретируется как-то так: title должно быть уникальным, исключая записи с id = null, где user_id = Auth::user()->id